# How to construct $\mathbb{R}^N$ where $N$ is a random variable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, foundations

How does one rigorously construct $\mathbb{R}^N$ where $N$ is a $\mathbb{Z}^{++}$-valued random variable on some Borel probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$?

Would someone be so kind to sketch out the main steps in such a construction? I believe that this problem was posed as a thought experiment on one of Terry Tao's blog posts, however I am now unable to find it.

Comment: I think you mean this post: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/real-analysis-relative-to-a-finite-measure-space/.

I remember well reading it on a break from a long hike, a few days before the wedding of a good friend - this is how I reconstructed the date :)